# dplyr join define NA values

Tags: r, left-join, dplyr, na

Can I define a "fill" value for NA in dplyr join? For example in the join define that all NA values should be 1?

```
require(dplyr)
lookup <- data.frame(cbind(c("USD","MYR"),c(0.9,1.1)))
names(lookup) <- c("rate","value")
fx <- data.frame(c("USD","MYR","USD","MYR","XXX","YYY"))
names(fx)[1] <- "rate"
left_join(x=fx,y=lookup,by=c("rate"))
```

Above code will create NA for values "XXX" and "YYY". In my case I am joining a large number of columns and there will be a lot of non-matches. All non-matches should have the same value. I know I can do it in several steps but the question is can all be done in one?
Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First off, I would like to recommend not to use the combination `data.frame(cbind(...))`. Here's why: `cbind` creates a `matrix` by default if you only pass atomic vectors to it. And matrices in R can only have one type of data (think of matrices as a vector with dimension attribute, i.e. number of rows and columns). Therefore, your code

```
cbind(c("USD","MYR"),c(0.9,1.1))
```

creates a character matrix:

```
str(cbind(c("USD","MYR"),c(0.9,1.1)))
# chr [1:2, 1:2] "USD" "MYR" "0.9" "1.1"
```

although you probably expected a final data frame with a character or factor column (rate) and a numeric column (value). But what you get is:

```
str(data.frame(cbind(c("USD","MYR"),c(0.9,1.1))))
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ X1: Factor w/ 2 levels "MYR","USD": 2 1
# $ X2: Factor w/ 2 levels "0.9","1.1": 1 2
```

because strings (characters) are converted to factors when using `data.frame` by default (You can circumvent this by specifying `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the `data.frame()` call).

I suggest the following alternative approach to create the sample data (also note that you can easily specify the column names in the same call):

```
lookup <- data.frame(rate = c("USD","MYR"), 
                     value = c(0.9,1.1))

fx <- data.frame(rate = c("USD","MYR","USD","MYR","XXX","YYY"))
```

Now, for you actual question, if I understand correctly, you want to replace all `NA`s with a `1` in the joined data. If that's correct, here's a custom function using `left_join` and `mutate_each` to do that:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join_NA <- function(x, y, ...) {
  left_join(x = x, y = y, by = ...) %>% 
    mutate_each(funs(replace(., which(is.na(.)), 1)))
}
```

Now you can apply it to your data like this:

```
> left_join_NA(x = fx, y = lookup, by = "rate")
#  rate value
#1  USD   0.9
#2  MYR   1.1
#3  USD   0.9
#4  MYR   1.1
#5  XXX   1.0
#6  YYY   1.0
#Warning message:
#joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
```

Note that you end up with a character column (rate) and a numeric column (value) and all NAs are replaced by 1.

```
str(left_join_NA(x = fx, y = lookup, by = "rate"))
#'data.frame':  6 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ rate : chr  "USD" "MYR" "USD" "MYR" ...
# $ value: num  0.9 1.1 0.9 1.1 1 1
```

Comment: first thanks for the comprehensive data creation hints. That's actually quite helpful for future questions. Second, your formula is neat and I will use it. many thanks!

Comment: why not just use `fx[is.na(fx)] <- 1`?

Comment: @rrs because this might be 1/2 way through a long dplyr chain

Comment: @nelsonauner there's also `tidyr`'s `replace_na()` and `fill()` commands.

Comment: `funs` is deprecated as of dplyr `0.8.0`

Comment: there's a `cbind.data.frame` ...

Answer (score 24):

If you're using dplyr anyway, you might as well take advantage of `dplyr::coalesce`, and use the dplyr syntax to pass into that a 1 or 0.  I think this looks nice...

```
... %>%
mutate_if(is.numeric,coalesce,0)
```

Where the `0` is the arg passed to `dplyr::coalesce` to replace NAs.

In the example in the question, there are dataframes with factors.  I feel confident one would not have FX rates as factors, or another vector in which you'd replace NA with zero, so I go ahead and add that step below just to make the answer executable after the provided example.

```
# replace NAs with zeros for all numeric columns
#
# ... code from question above
left_join(x=fx,y=lookup,by=c("rate")) %>%
    # ignore if factors in value column are because it's a toy example
    mutate(value = as.numeric(as.character(value))) %>%
    # the good stuff here
    mutate_if(is.numeric,coalesce,0)
```

Comment: Nice one!  Beautiful syntax.

Comment: Or, with the newer tidy-select syntax: `mutate(across(where(is.numeric), coalesce, 0))`

Answer (score 8):

I stumbled on the same problem with dplyr and wrote a small function that solved my problem. (the solution requires tidyr and dplyr)

```
left_join0 <- function(x, y, fill = 0L){
  z <- left_join(x, y)
  tmp <- setdiff(names(z), names(x))
  z <- replace_na(z, setNames(as.list(rep(fill,   length(tmp))), tmp))
  z
}
```

Originally answered at: [R Left Outer Join with 0 Fill Instead of NA While Preserving Valid NA's in Left Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186694/r-left-outer-join-with-0-fill-instead-of-na-while-preserving-valid-nas-in-left/41569043#41569043)

Answer (score 7):

A `tidyverse` solution is to use `tidyr::replace_na` after the join:

```r
left_join(x = fx, y = lookup, by = c("rate")) %>% 
  replace_na(list(value = 0))
```

Or, for more general cases:

```r
left_join(x = fx, y = lookup, by = c("rate")) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ replace_na(.x, 0)))
```